# Monitor system (kernel) load on linux

Tags: linux, bash, kernel-module, monitor

I am working on a project which consists of a kernel distributed network file system.

I reached the point where I am testing my implementation. For that I would like to monitor the CPU load of it and by this I am referring to the kernel load of my module.

As I understood from a similar post there is no way of monitoring the load of a kernel module, therefore I was wondering which would be the best way to do it?

An example of testing my app would be to run the `dd` command in parallel.
At the moment I am using `pidstat -c "dd" -p ALL` to monitor the system load of command dd. At the same time I am looking at the `top` tool (`top -d 0.2` to  see more 'accurate' values).

With all these I do not feel confident that my way of monitoring is pretty accurate.

Any advice is highly appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like [collectd](https://collectd.org/) to monitor all sorts of metrics, possibly showing it with [Graphite](http://graphite.wikidot.com/) for a simple overview with some processing tools (like averages over time).

That said, rather than monitoring the **CPU load** you could measure the **throughput**. By loading the system as much as you can you should be easily able to pinpoint which resource is the bottleneck: Disk I/O, network I/O, CPU, memory, or something else. And for a distributed network file system, you'll want to ensure that the bottleneck is very clearly disk or network I/O.

Comment: Thank you l0b0 for your detailed answer. The thing is that I am developing a FS which is stored in the main memory therefore Disk IO is not my point. Also, network is not primary focus(there are a lot of tools to do that, simply googling it). What I was looking for is to track the CPU load for my kernel module, or a smart way compared to what I explained. Any idea? :)